# Error of derivative approximation

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, approximation

I have a task to approximate the value of $f'(x_0)$ with error of $O(h^2)$, knowing the values of $f$ in points: $x_0,\ x_1=x_0+h,\ x_2=x_0+2h$. I used Taylor equation with Peano Remainder for $x_1,\ x_2$ and I've got:
$$
f(x_2)-4f(x_1)=-3f(x_0)-2hf'(x_0)+O(4h^2)-4O(h^2)\\ f'(x_0)= \frac{1}{2h}(4f(x_1)-f(x_2)-3f(x_0))+? 
$$
this question mark (?) is the error - my question: ***how to prove that it is*** $O(h^2)$?

Comment: As it stands, it won't be. You have an error term of $O(h^2)$ which when divided by $h$ will be $O(h)$.

Comment: @Mikal so I should use Taylor equation with $O(h^3)$? But there will be third derivative in the equation and I only know value of $f$ in these points, not $f'''$

Comment: You need to compute the 2nd order Taylor approximation at both $x_1$ and $x_2$, then make the terms that actually are of 2nd order cancer. See my complete answer below. Would you also care to change the title to osmething like
""Prove forward finite difference approximation is of second order"""
Such that future readers can also find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume first $f\in C^3$ such that we can compute the second order Taylor approximation of $f(x)$ around $x_0$ with Lagrange remainder.

**First scenario.**
Assume $x_1 = x_0 + h$ and $x_2 = x_0 + 2h$. We approximate $f$ as its Taylor approximation around $x_0$ at $x_1$
$$
f(x_0 + h) = f(x_0) + hf'(x_0) + \frac{h^2}{2} f''(x_0) + \frac{h^3}{6} f'''(c_1) \tag{1} \label{1}
$$
where $c_1\in [x_0, x_0 + h]$, and at $x_2$
$$
f(x_0 + 2h) = f(x_0) + 2hf'(x_0) + 4\frac{h^2}{2} f''(x_0) + 8\frac{h^3}{6} f'''(c_2) \tag{2} \label{2}
$$
where $c_2 \in [x_0, x_0 + 2h]$. Now subtract \eqref{2} from \eqref{1} multiplied by the weights $1$ and $4$ such that 
$$
f(x_0+2h) - 4f(x_0+h) = f(x_0) - 4f(x_0) + 2hf'(x_0) - 4hf'(x_0) + 4\frac{h^2}{2}f''(x_0) - 4\frac{h^2}{2}f''(x_0) + 8\frac{h^3}{6} f'''(c_2) - \frac{h^3}{6} f'''(c_1)
$$
Observe that the second order terms cancel and we remove these. We also rewrite the third order terms to big-O notation as
$$
f(x_0+2h) - 4f(x_0+h) = -3 f(x_0) - 2hf'(x_0) + O(h^3)
$$
which we can move around to show that
$$
f'(x_0) = \frac{1}{2} \left[4f(x_0 + h) - 3f(x_0) - f(x_0 + 2h)\right] + O(h^2).
$$

**Second scenario.**
We can also investigate the (somewhat weird) scenario in which we have $x_1 = x_0 + h$ (as before) and $x_2 = x_0 - 2h$. Then the Taylor approximation around $x_0$ evaluated at $x_2$ is given by
$$
f(x_0 - 2h) = f(x_0) - 2hf'(x_0) + 4\frac{h^2}{2}f''(x_0) - 8\frac{h^3}{6}f'''(c_3) \tag{3} \label{3}
$$
with $c_3 \in [x_0 - 2h, x_0]$. We subtract \eqref{3} and \eqref{1} multiplied with $1$ and $4$ and arrive at
$$
f(x_0 - 2h) - 4 f(x_0 + h) = f(x_0) - 4f(x_0) -2hf'(x_0) - 4hf'(x_0) + 4\frac{h^2}{2}f''(x_0) - 4\frac{h^2}{2}f''(x_0) - 8 \frac{h^3}{6}f'''(c_3) - 4\frac{h^3}{6}f'''(c_1)
$$
As before we notice that the second order terms cancel and we replace the third order terms using big-O notation. This simplifies to
$$
f(x_0 - 2h) - 4 f(x_0 + h) = f(x_0) - 4f(x_0) -6hf'(x_0) + O(h^3)
$$
which we can flip around
$$
f'(x_0) = \frac{1}{6h}\left[4f(x_0 + h) - 3f(x_0) - f(x_0 - 2h)\right] + O(h^2)
$$

Comment: yeah I did excatly that, but shouldn't there be$ f(x_0 + h) = f(x_0) + hf'(x_0) + \frac{h^2}{2} f''(x_0) + O(h^2)$ instead of $O(h^3)$? Or did I just just messed up the equation?

Comment: Using the Peano form of the remainder this is what we get yes. But if we can assume that $f \in C^3$ then we can use the Lagrange remainder
$$
f(x_0 + h) = f(x_0) + h f'(x_0) + \frac{h^2}{2} f''(x_0) + \frac{h^3}{6} f'''(c)
$$
for $c \in [x_0, x_0 + h]$. Such that if $f'''(x')$ is bounded in the interval $[x_0, x_0 + h]$ (which happens if $f \in C^3$) then the final error term is of order $O(h^3)$.

Comment: I updated my answer such that it mentions this explicity.

Comment: and how to show that $8\frac{h^3}{6} f'''(c_2) - \frac{h^3}{6} f'''(c_1)=O(h^3)$?

Comment: and would this method also work for $x_1=x_0+h,\ x_2=x_0-2h$ (where the arguments are not evenly spaced)

Comment: I added this scenario to my answer. Yes, as long as you have three points you can make the second order terms cancel such that when you divide by $h$ so that your error term is of second order.